# Next.js Query param get lost on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, query-string, dynamic-routing

I have 2 components and i need to route between them and passing data from the first to the second and not send the param in the url. but my problem is when I refresh the page the query params get lost.

```
 <p className={styles.jobname}>
        <Link
          href={{
            pathname: `alyDeal/` + `${jobId}`,
            query: {
              jobName,
              desc,
              subcat,
              city,
              est,
              bids,
              userId,
              name,
              picture,
              jobId,
              jobImages,
              budget,
              neigh,
              score,
              phone,
              email,
              deadline,
              jobAddress,
              createdAt,
              ownedBus,
              category,
            },
          }}
          as={`/alyDeal/${jobId}`}
          passHref={true}
        >
          {jobName}
        </Link>
      </p>
```

and in the second component

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  {
    const { query } = context;
    return { props: { query } };
  }

const { query } = props;
  console.log(query);
```

and the query always returns only the id that I'm passing directly into the URL but not the rest of the query object

Any solutions?
};

Comment: Losing the parameters on page refresh will always be the case when hiding parameters from the URL. If you need the hidden params across page reloads then you either do not hide the params at all (that's what query params are for - to pass/persist a certain context), or persist the values you need on the client-side (localStorage or cookies).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't read the query directly in the page? You don't need to use props.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { query } = router

  // use the query data

  return (
    <div>JSON.stringify(query)</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The problem is after refreshing the page, the query object only holds the id (jobId) param which is sent directly in the URL, other query params values are lost.

Comment: I see your problem, did you try to remove the query from the `pathname` parameter? And leave all queries within the `query` parameter? i.e. set `pathname: "aalyDeal"`. Since your're double setting values, the URL object might be taking only what is set in the `pathname` param